# Where can I find *all* screensaver files on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, screensaver

When I go to "Desktop & Screen Saver", I see about 20 different screensavers. All online resources I've found have directed me to one of these locations, none of which contain ALL of the screensavers. In particular, I just want to edit/poke around in the .saver file for the Floating screensaver.

I can only find the abstract art screensavers like Flurry, Arabesque, Shell, Word of the Day, Random. There are other screen savers I can use, like Floating, Flip-up, Reflections, Origami, ...

**Where are all of the other screensavers?**

I've looked in these folders:

```
/Library/Screen Savers
    (only contains a folder with a bunch of pictures)
~/Library/Screen Savers
    (empty)
/System/Library/Screen Savers
    (only contains abstract screen savers mentioned above)
/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources 
    (contains a bunch of irrelevant files)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Mojave you have two kinds of screensavers:

- The **abstract** ones (these are the ones you already found: `/System/Library/Screen Savers`)
- The **slideshows**: `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Slideshows.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Content/Styles`